# How to access object property as a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

I can do var `foobar = foo.bar`to access the bar variable.

How would I do this if I had an arbitrary string that told me what element I needed to access. `foo."bar"` doesn't work.

Comment: Computed is so [], but the way you initially do is also using strings... and every property has a string as name. You can't say "access object property as a string" since it's always string, e.g., the first value at computed index [] casts into string too, so `a[0]` is `a['0']`

Comment: if `bar="bat"` then `foo[bar]` would get you `foo.bat`

Answer (score 1):

I think

`foo["bar"]`

is the syntax you need